# docker and bitnami/phppgadmin: How to connect to the remote postgresql database

Tags: docker, bitnami, postgresql-12, phppgadmin

I am trying to connect to a remote postgresql database using the `bitnami/phppgadmin` docker

How to mention the host name

```
  phppgadmin:
    image: "bitnami/phppgadmin:7.13.0"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - '443:8443'
    environment:
      PHP_PG_ADMIN_SERVER_HOST: 'xx.xx.xx.xx'
      PHP_PG_ADMIN_SERVER_PORT: 5432
```

I am trying this, but i am not able to login in the dash board.

I have set the env variables based on the `dockage/phppgadmin`. BUt bitnami has no such `options`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every image on Docker Hub has a corresponding page; you can look at https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/phppgadmin.  That has an "Environment variables" section, which documents:

> The phpPgAdmin instance can be customized by specifying environment variables on the first run. The following environment values are provided to custom phpPgAdmin:
>
> - `DATABASE_HOST`: Database server host. Default: **postgresql**.

So use `DATABASE_HOST` as the environment variable name.  There is also `DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER` but you don't need to explicitly set it to the PostgreSQL default value.